# Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.LiveUnitTesting.Runtime, version= 1.7.0.0' with visual studio 2017

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, visual-studio, visual-studio-2017, live-unit-tests

I started live unit testing with visual studio 2017 (15.7.1). After I switch the branch and start the project, an error message comes up saying the following:

> Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.LiveUnitTesting.Runtime, version= 1.7.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35' or one of its dependenc

[image]

I tried to:
 - rebuild/restart the project
 - stop live unit testing
but it didn't work.

I don't know why load 'Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.LiveUnitTesting.Runtime' from project/bin.
Anyone have a suggestion?

Comment: I see the file here **C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Enterprise\Common7\IDE\CommonExtensions\Microsoft\ManagedLanguages\VBCSharp\LiveUnitTesting\Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.LiveUnitTesting.Runtime.dll**

Comment: thanks, it is weird to load from  from project/bin. :)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Finally, I stop live unit test and delete Persisted Data. It works now.

Step 1. Stop unit test
[image]

Step 2. Test → Live Testing → Options...
[image]

Step 3. delete Persisted Data
[image]

Step 4. Delete all folder under package folder, and then re-build Solution, it works.

hm... I still don't know why load from project/bin after changing branch :S.

Comment: Thank you! "Deleted Persisted Data" did the trick for me!

Answer (score 0):

I had the same error with VS2019, in an existing Project with unit tests working with my colleagues. I ended up updating Visual Studio to version 16.2.3, and its working now.